# How do I use a for loop in a django template?

Tags: django, templates, view, for-loop

In my django view, I have a list that looks like the above (except 50 lists embedded within the big list.
In my template, how do I use a for loop to reference to display each of the elements within every list?

I am also trying to access a particular element within a list, for example the element 'c' in the below example.  I tried feed[0][1] in the template but received an error.

```
feed = [ [0,a,b,c], [1,d,e,f], ... ] 

{% for video in feed %}
#not sure what to put here
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{% for video in feed %}
    {%for item in video %}
         {{item}} {% comment %} render it appropriately {% endcomment %}
    {%endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

`video` is again a list so you can again iterate over it to get `item` in it and use it to render appropriate html.

EDIT: With reference to comment by #jdi and updated question, if you want to access particular element of list you can do:

```
{% video in feed %}
    {{ video.3 }}    {% comment %} To access 3rd element {% endcomment %}
    {{ video|last }} {% comment %} To access last element {% endcomment %}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can pick a specific element within the list?  For example, how would I just pick the character 'c' in the above list?  I tried doing item[3] but didn't work.

Comment: I will vote up this answer, but I think the {comment} might get confused for bad code since thats not a valid HTML comment. You should just remove it or comment with `<!-- comment -->` or the django comment tag `{% comment %} comment {% endcomment %}`

Comment: @sharataka: Instead of doing the second `for` loop, you would just access it by index: `{{ video.3 }}` or `{{ video|last }}`

Comment: @jdi, `{# ... #}` is django template syntax for single line comment. I agree it doesn't look good in the SO code syntax.

Comment: @Rohan: Dang it I over looked that variation. I apologize. You can revert my changes. I still voted you up

Comment: @jdi, never mind and thanks! I kept that because it _looks_ good in the SO syntax!

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
 {%for D in TablePivot %}
     <tr class="{% cycle row1,row2 %}">
        {%for valor in D %}
        <td>{{valor}}</td>
        {%endfor%}
    </tr>
 {%endfor%}
```